# Objective C : How to Pass Instance Variable of a singleton class to other class from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose I am creating a **static library** and in which I have two **`NSObject`** Classes Named as **`ClassA`** and **`ClassB`**, User can Access **`ClassA.h`** to execute the functions inside **`library`**. Now I've some functions defined into **`ClassB`** and I want user to execute these functions from their **`ViewController`** as per their need but I don't want to give **`ClassB.h`** to user so how user can access it using **`ClassA`**.

**ClassA.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject

+ (void) method_1;
+ (void) method_2;
+ (void) method_3;
//  Tried to pass Instance of ClassB to user ViewController

+ (id) getClassBInstanceObject;

@end
```

**ClassA.m**

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassA

+ (void) method_1 {
//Some Stuffs Done Here !!
}

+ (void) method_2 {
//Some Stuffs Done Here !!
}

+ (void) method_3 {
//Some Stuffs Done Here !!
}

//  Tried to pass Instance of ClassB to user ViewController

+ (id) getClassBInstanceObject {
 id objB = [ClassB sharedInstance];
    return objB;
}

@end
```

**ClassB.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassB : NSObject

+ (id)sharedInstance;
-(void)Test_ClassB_function;
@end
```

**ClassB.m**

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassB

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static ClassB *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    });
    return instance;
}
-(void)Test_ClassB_function {
    NSLog(@"this is the method called from ClassB !!!!");
}

@end
```

Now User Have a **Static library FAT (`lib.a`) file** and **`ClassA.h`** File Which He'll include in his project and then he can import **`ClassA.h`** into his **`ViewController`** Class to execute library functions and user wants to execute **`Test_ClassB_function`** using **`ClassA`**.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ClassA.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
[ClassA method_1];
[ClassA method_2];
[ClassA method_3];
}

- (IBAction)Button1:(id)sender {
id class_B_Object = [ClassA getClassBInstanceObject];

[class_B_Object Test_ClassB_function];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this goal in Objective-C.

Comment: Methods should not be o]prefixed with get nor should they contain _.

Comment: I was aware they shouldn’t start with underscores, what is the rationale behind avoiding underscores inside? Sure, in general you should camelCase, but I’ve used it in the past to map other identifiers to selectors. Is that dangerous?

Comment: Not dangerous, just nonstandard.  There are cases for it here and there, but not all over the place as it is here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

In ClassA.h

```
+ (void) testClassBFunctionFromClassA;
```

In ClassA.m

```
+ (void) testClassBFunctionFromClassA{

    [[ClassB sharedInstance] Test_ClassB_function];

}
```

In ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)Button1:(id)sender {
    [ClassA testClassBFunctionFromClassA];
}
```

Comment: This is a temporary solution In this case I need to create different method for all ClassB method into ClassA. And If ClassB Object accessible then no need to create this